# Angular Http GET Request \ Response not showing when called from ngOnInit

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on an a new Angular project and I am relatively new to working with Angular.

I have code that on a page event fires and returns the data as expected, however, on ngOnInit this is calling the API, the API is returning data, however the result is not being populated in the calling ts file.

I have been stepping through the code, and cannot see a reason why this is not working.

The code is as follows.

```
export class GetDeadLettersComponent implements OnInit {

// constructor ommited

ngOnInit() {
  this.loadData();
}

loadData() {
  var pageEvent = new PageEvent();
  pageEvent.pageIndex = this.defaultPageIndex;
  pageEvent.pageSize = this.defaultPageSize;
  this.getData(pageEvent);
}

getData(event: PageEvent) {
  console.log(event);
  var url = 'https://localhost:7179/api/v1/dead-letters';
  var params = new HttpParams()
    .set("MessageCount", event.pageSize.toString())

    this.http.get<any>(url, { params }).subscribe(result => {
      this.paginator.length = result.totalCount;
      this.paginator.pageIndex = result.pageIndex;
      this.paginator.pageSize = result.pageSize;
      this.deadletters = new MatTableDataSource<DeadLetter>(result.messages);
    })
  }
}
```

When outputting the values of result and result.message from the ngOnInit I see an empty response.

When triggering from a page event, this is returning data in the same I was expecting.

When outputting the page event object this is as expected each time, and the API is returning the expected data too.

Any and all help would be gratefully received.

---- Edit ----

I have now found that going direct to the URL this also works, so it is an issue with the routing.  However, am still unsure as to how or why.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { GetDeadLettersComponent } from './dead-letters/get/get-dead-letters.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'dead-letters/get', component: GetDeadLettersComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

--- Edit 2 ---

HTML

```
<h1>Dead Letters</h1>

<p *ngIf="!deadletters"><em>Loading...</em></p>


<table mat-table 
    [dataSource]="deadletters" 
    class="table-striped mat-elevation-z8" 
    [hidden]="!deadletters"
    >

  <!-- Id Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="messageId">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Message Id</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let deadletter"> {{deadletter.messageId}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- body -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="body">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Body</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let deadletter"> {{deadletter.body}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Reason -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="reason">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Reason</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let deadletter"> {{deadletter.userProperties[0][0]}} </td>
  </ng-container>
   
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>

<!-- Pagination directive -->
<mat-paginator [hidden]="!deadletters"
    (page)="getData($event)"
    [pageSize]="10"
    [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20, 50]"
    ></mat-paginator>
```

Comment: Can you please add the HTML file?

Comment: How are you getting to the route?  Does a page refresh work?  Note that `ngOnInit` will not automatically fire for router navigation to the same page.

Comment: @PankajParkar added as requested

Comment: @Patrick, I am getting to the route by clicking the link at the top of the nav bar

Comment: @Patrick the navigation route I am getting to the home page, then I am clicking the link in the nav bar, and then its taking an age to get results and then returning nothing

Comment: Just for check, aren't you having a CORS error? Because angular app runs on a port and backend on another.

Comment: @Vanderson there isnt a CORS issue, im watching the entire thing all night so far and working with it, the ngOnInit isnt firing and I am there not getting the data I am expecting to see without a hard refresh or changing some page values

Comment: So ngOnInit isn't firyng at all? This is weird. Have you put the @Component anotation?

Comment: Does you component actually `implements OnInit`?

Comment: @mat.hudak yes it looks like this `export class GetDeadLettersComponent implements OnInit {`... }

Comment: @Vanderson I am getting console logs out from it so ngOnInit is firing, but when its getting through to loads data Im not getting my data back like I am when I am navigating direct to the URL or creating a page event